# Some answers in post.xml have no OwnerId in data dump: deleted users?

Tags: discussion, data-dump

There are some entries within post.xml with `PostTypeId="2"` that have no `OwnerUserId`.  E.g.:

```
<row Id="40844" 
PostTypeId="2" 
ParentId="40773" 
CreationDate="2008-09-02T22:36:42.593" 
Score="1" 
ViewCount="0" 
Body="blah, blah, blah" 
LastActivityDate="2008-09-02T22:36:42.593" 
Tags="" />
```

Can I assume the users was deleted?  Or maybe there is some behavior of SO that I am unaware of....hmmm...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would make sense. Visiting [post #40844](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40773/ticket-tracking-software-w-good-email-integration-and-decent-navigation/40844#40844.) reveals that that user was indeed deleted.

Comment: visit the post?  that, honestly, never occured to me :p  To wrapped up in the data...sigh...